# Socket Programming three way handshake (PYTHON) with TCP

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

So I am working on a project that requires me to simulate a TCP three handshake protocol using UDP. I want to divided the project into two parts: the first is to establish and close connection; the second is to implement the flow control protocol without any package loss. Since the client and server will be interacting with each other, so I need two sockets, which means I also need two ports - 19990 and 19991 - to send and receive data between client and server.

I am having trouble with the three way handshake

1. Client -> (Send SYN)
2. Sever -> (Receive SYN and Send SYN ACK)
3. Client -> Receives SYN ACK and Sends ACK with Data
4. Server then establishes a connection and says that data has been received
5. Client -> Server ACK the connection & received data. So send FIN to close the connection
6. Server -> Receives FIN and closes the connection (with server_socket.close)

**output on the client side:**

1. Send: a,1
2. Receive: b, num:2
3. Send: c,3
4. Receive: d, num:4
5. Client done

**output on server side:**

1. Receive: a, num:1
2. Send: b,2
3. Receive c, num:3
4. Send: d,4
5. Server done.

**However, what I am hoping for them to look like is like so:**

**client.py**

1. Send SYN
2. Send: ,1
3. Receive: num,2
4. Received SYN-ACK. Send ACK & Data
5. Send: I love ABC University in New York City.,3
6. Receive: ,num:4
7. Received ACK for data. Send FIN. Connection closed.
8. Send: ,4

**server.py**

1. Receive: ,num: 1
2. Received SYN. Send SYN-ACK
3. Send: ,2
4. Receive: I love ABC University in New York City.,num:3
5. Receive ACK. Connection Established. Received Data. Send ACK
6. Send: ,4
7. Receive: ,num:4
8. Connection Closed

**Here is the code I have for server.py:**

```
import socket
import sys
import struct

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 19990))


def send(c,num):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    ss = struct.pack("!50si",c.encode(),num)
    s.sendto(ss,("127.0.0.1",19991))
    s.close()
    print("Send:%s,%d" % (c,num))


def recv():
    global server_socket
    data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    str,num = struct.unpack("!50si",data)
    str = str.decode("utf-8").replace("\0","")
    print("Receive:%s,num:%d" % (str,num))
    return str,num

while True:
    str,num = recv()
    num = num + 1
    str = chr(ord(str)+1)
    send(str,num)
    if str == "d":
        break

print("Server Done.")
server_socket.close()
```

**Here is the code I have for client.py**

```
import socket
import sys
import struct



server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 19991))


def send(c,num):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    ss = struct.pack("!50si",c.encode(),num)
    s.sendto(ss,("127.0.0.1",19990))
    s.close()
    print("Send:%s,%d" % (c,num))

def recv():
    global server_socket
    data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    str,num = struct.unpack("!50si",data)
    str = str.decode("utf-8").replace("\0","")
    print("Receive:%s,num:%d" % (str,num))
    return str,num


str = 'a'
num = 1
while True:
    send(str,num)
    str,num = recv()
    if str == "d":
        break
    str = chr(ord(str)+1)
    num = num + 1

print("Client done.")
server_socket.close()

#If the number = 1, sender will send and the receiver will receive
#c is the data and num is the sequence number, for the first three msgs it is the flag
#The payload we want to send is seven characters with one sentence
#Window size is 4 with 4 being four characters
#First package is "i lo"
#I is sent as a package, then space as a package, then l as a package, and o as a package as a window
#First byte is i, second is space, l is third, o is forth.
#Send out 4 bytes, receive 4 acknowledgements. 
#When the sender sends out the last byte "."
#To do: Change 'a' to past establishment

#Instead of Send: a, 1 
#professor wants to see "Send Think message"
#Receive: Think ack message
#Send: Ack msg 
#a b c d are just give you some examples
```